# Do practical blind signature schemes make compromises?

Tags: blind-signature

I am fascinated by the idea of blind signatures and their applications introduced by David Chaum for electronic cash and voting and his provided analogy with carbon copy is quite compelling. However looking into some schemes, as one in Wikipedia, I see that in contrast to an ordinary cryptographic signature scheme where the hash of a message is signed in blind signature schemes message is signed directly as provided by the user. Is it a security issue for such schemes?

For example, let's consider a transparent setup where blind signatures are published in one list (together with identities in the roster) and their decryptions into another one in randomized order. Additionally, an adversary has access to unlimited queries (for example, through a coalition) as he wishes. Would that allow an adversary to either unblind the signatures, forge them or even extract signers key?